# I can't open SQL Server 2017 Setup.exe file

Tags: sql-server

I just uninstalled my existing SQL server 2017 but this happened when I tried to re-install it. I might've incorrectly uninstalled something. I have no idea how to repair this, I already searched about this but I can't seem to find a solution.

[setup.exe error image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/p3Puw.png)

Comment: Have you rebooted since you uninstalled it? Sometimes there are delete/cleanup tasks that need to happen during a system reboot.

Comment: Also, where are you trying to install it from? The modified timestamps on the folders in your screenshot are 2022-07-12... much later than SQL Server 2017 setup files and folders should be. SQL Server doesn't support installation FROM nor TO compressed volumes and folders.

Comment: @AlwaysLearning Yes, many times already but it still has the error

Comment: @AlwaysLearning I transferred the files from another folder.